# Multi-Input Keras Model Using flow_from_dataframe

Tags: python, keras

I've been trying to run a Siamese network.  At this point, I'm just trying to get it to run.  My current iteration uses a pandas dataframe to determine which images to load.  The dataframe has columns for Anchor_Id, Positive_Id, Negative_Id, and corresponding file names under Anchor_Image, Positive_Image, Negative_Image.  I'm using a Triplet loss function to determine the differences in image embeddings.

Right now my error is that the model expects 3 arrays, but it's only receiving a list of 1 array.  I know that generator_generator_triplet (seen below) is putting these flows into a list, but this seems to work in other iterations of this model.  My previous problem was that I needed my final embedding model to have a Dense layer with exactly as many nodes as categories (roughly 5000).  This didn't make sense to me, and I think that problem was related to the models feeding the one-hot label vector along with the X values (images).

Some of this code came from various stackoverflow and Keras github posts, but I'm unable to get everything to work under one hood.

If someone could help me, even by reworking what I've got below, I'd be ecstatic.  I've read every post I could find about triplet loss, but nothing specifically existed that included the use of multiple flow_from_dataframe instances.

```
bs = 32

train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/.255,
                                     shear_range = 0.2,
                                     zoom_range = 0.2,
                                     horizontal_flip = False)


def generate_generator_triplet(generator, df, path1, batch_size, img_height, img_width):
    gen_anchor = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = df,
                                          directory = path1,
                                          x_col = 'Anchor_Image',
                                          y_col = 'Anchor_Id',
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=8,
                                          drop_duplicates = False)

    gen_pos = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = df,
                                          directory = path1,
                                          x_col = 'Pos_Image',
                                          y_col = 'Pos_Id',
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=8,
                                          drop_duplicates = False)

    gen_neg = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = df,
                                          directory = path1,
                                          x_col = 'Neg_Image',
                                          y_col = 'Neg_Id',
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=8,
                                          drop_duplicates = False)


    while True:
            Anchori = gen_anchor.next()
            Posi = gen_pos.next()
            Negi = gen_neg.next()
            yield [Anchori[0], Posi[0], Negi[0]], Anchori[1]

inputgenerator = generate_generator_triplet(generator=train_gen,
                                           df = new,
                                           path1=path,
                                           batch_size=bs,
                                           img_height=128,
                                           img_width=128)

## Triplet Loss
ALPHA = .2

def triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, alpha = ALPHA):


    anchor, pos, neg = y_pred[0], y_pred[1], y_pred[2]

    pos_dist = K.sum(K.square(anchor - pos), axis = 0)
    neg_dist = K.sum(K.square(anchor - neg), axis = 0)

    loss = K.maximum(pos_dist - neg_dist + alpha, 0.0)

    return loss


## Model Construction

data_input = Input(shape = [128,128,3])
siam = Conv2D(64, (4,4), strides = (1,1))(data_input)
siam = Activation(activation = 'relu')(siam)
siam = Conv2D(128, (5,5), strides = (1,1))(siam)
siam = Activation(activation = 'relu')(siam)
siam = MaxPooling2D()(siam)

siam = Flatten()(siam)
siam = Dense(64)(siam)
siam = Activation(activation = 'relu')(siam)

siam = Dense(512)(siam)
out = Activation(activation = 'sigmoid')(siam)

siam_model = Model(inputs = data_input, outputs = out)

anchor_input = Input(shape = [128, 128, 3])
pos_input = Input(shape = [128, 128, 3])
neg_input = Input(shape = [128, 128, 3])

anchor_embed = siam_model(anchor_input)
pos_embed = siam_model(pos_input)
neg_embed = siam_model(neg_input)

optimizer = Adam(0.00006)

siamese_net = Model(inputs = [anchor_input, pos_input, neg_input],
                    outputs = [anchor_embed, pos_embed, neg_embed])

siamese_net.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = triplet_loss, metrics = ['accuracy'])

siamese_net.summary()

siamese_net.fit_generator(inputgenerator,
                steps_per_epoch = len(new)/bs,
                epochs = 5,
                shuffle = False
                #,validation_data = ([test_left, test_right], test_targets)
                )
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am also facing the same issue. I am also creating siamese network with 3 multiple inputs and I am not able to pass them through ImageDataGenerator specifically flow_from_dataframe().

Comment: I never was able to solve the problem.  I gave up and decided to work on problems like this in TensorFlow in the future.  I do feel like this should have worked, but it does not.